# Jquery not found when using Node and express

Tags: jquery, node.js, express

I looked an a few similar questions on stack (like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17732590/jquery-in-html-with-node-js-as-backend))but none of them seem to help me, even though my issue seems similar.

I am new to node and server side scripting and would prefer to not use more frameworks/components.

I have a drawing app written fully in javascript (jquery) and I want to host it using node as my backend.

My folder structure is like this:

```
├── README.md
├── app.js
├── css
├── db.js
├── model.js
├── package.json
├── public
│   ├── css
│   │   └── simple.css
│   └── js
│       ├── jquery.min.js
│       └── testjs.js
├── route.js
├── schema.sql
├── schema_macaronic.sql
├── node_modules +
└── views
    ├── 404.jade
    ├── index.jade
    ├── signin.jade
    └── signup.jade
```

All of my code is in `public/js/testjs.js`.  testjs.js uses jquery, underscore and some other js libraries. I would like to call functions in this file in my views `index.jade`, `signin.jade` etc.

I have the following line in my `app.js`

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));    
app.use('/jquery', express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/public/js')));
```

and in `signin.jade` I looks like this:

```
doctype html
html(lang='en')
    head
        link(rel='stylesheet', href='/css/simple.css')
        script(type="type/javascript",src="/jquery/jquery.min.js")
        //script(type="type/javascript",src="js/testjs.js")
        title #{title}
    body
        script.
            $(document).ready(function() {
                console.log('hello form js and jquery')
            });
        h2 Sign In Form
        form(method='post', action='/signin')
            p
                label(for='username') username
                input#username(type='text', name='username', placeholder='username', required='true')
            p
                label(for='password') password
                input#password(type='text', name='password', placeholder='password', required='true')
            p
                input#signin(type='submit', name='signin', value='sign in')
                a(href='/signup', title='register') register
```

When i reach the index page I see a `Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined`
at line 10 (`$(document).ready(function()`)

What am I doing wrong? The entire project is [here](https://github.com/arendu/simplelogin) on github.

Note: the css is working (color changes to red based on css in `public/css/simple.css`.

Also, I need more that just jquery on the client side, I have around 2-3 js files that are meant to be run on client side, how can I make them also visible to the client side views?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok It is something to do with `doctype html` and  `html(lang='en')` removing it seems to make it work. (makes sense because its not html?)

New jade view:

```
doctype
html
    head
        title #{title}
        link(type='text/css', rel='stylesheet', href='/css/simple.css')
        script(type='text/javascript', src='/js/jquery.min.js')
        script(type='text/javascript', src='/js/testjs.js')
    body
        script.
            $(document).ready(function() {
                console.log('hello form js and jquery')
                helloinfile('adi')
            });
        h2 Sign In Form

        form(method='post', action='/signin')
            p
                label(for='username') username
                input#username(type='text', name='username', placeholder='username', required='true')
            p
                label(for='password') password
                input#password(type='text', name='password', placeholder='password', required='true')
            p
                input#signin(type='submit', name='signin', value='sign in')
                a(href='/signup', title='register') register
```

I can see both the console messages from `console.log` and from `helloinfile`. The full code is update on  [github](https://github.com/arendu/simplelogin).

Answer (score 2):

In the `app.js`, **alter** the lines:

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));    
app.use('/jquery', express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/public/js')));
```

**To:**

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
```

This way, all css and js files can be accessed.

**Jade file** (the `jquery` path is wrong in your code):

```
link(rel='stylesheet', href='/css/simple.css')
script(type="type/javascript",src="/js/jquery.min.js")
```

Comment: The error `Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined` do not means the Jquery not loaded, but can be caused the version of Jquery (some function do not work in different versions) or the order of the loading of the libraries, some like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2075337/uncaught-referenceerror-is-not-defined

Comment: I get the same error for any external js file.. for example in my code i have '/js/testjs.js' which has a function called 'somefunc' .. i get 'Uncaught ReferenceError: somefunc is not defined' if I call it from jade.

Answer (score 1):

You should just use

```
script(type="type/javascript",src="/js/jquery.min.js")
```

And get rid of this line:

```
app.use('/jquery', express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/public/js')));
```

Comment: added the '/' it still does not work.. I still get the same error.

Comment: both /js/jquery.min.js and /jquery/jquery.min.js give the same error. Also it is not just limited to jquery... any external js file is not visible to jade.

Comment: try eliminating the line at the bottom of my answer ```app.use```... etc.

Comment: can you tell us what ```http://localhost:{port-you-use}/js/jquery.min.js``` return in your browser?

Comment: still does not work i added the '/' app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

Comment: What I'm interested in is if you can hit ```http://localhost:{port-you-use}/js/jquery.min.js``` in your browser so in your case it would be ```http://localhost:3000/js/jquery.min.js```. Do you see a file when you do this? Also have you removed the ```app.use``` line from my comment above ^

Comment: Yes I can see the the file when i type in : http://localhost:3000/js/jquery.min.js ---- so maybe the js files are loading after jade tries to call them?? And yes I removed the redundent app.use

Comment: now that the ```app.use``` line is gone, you'll need to change your jquery path to ```/js/jquery.min.js``` as I suggested ^ let me know if that works

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91777/discussion-between-adi-and-jimi).